# Python, How to organize a big function that relies on many external data to work

Tags: python, function, class, organization

Question: How to organize a big function that relies on many external data to work. should I declare a class and contain those external data? or should I keep the big function and its data in one file? Or there are better ways of doing it?what's the most computationally efficient way? what's the most pythonic, recommended way?

I have a log file to parse, and the log file contains many formats of strings. I wrote a parseLine(inputStr) function to deal with all possible formats. The parseLine() function requires many precompiled regexes, and a quite big dictionary for lookups. I kept the parseLine() function in a file parseLineFile.py

My parseLineFile.py looks like:

```
regex0 = re.compile('foo')
regex1 = re.compile('bar')
# and many more regexes

set0 = {'f', '0'}
set1 = {'b', 'a'} # could be a big set contains 10s of strings
# and many more sets

def parseLine(inputString, inputDictionary, inputTimeCriteria):
    # pseduo code:
    #   use regex0 to extract date info in inputString
    #   check if date within inputTimeCriteria
    #   use more of previous declared regexes and sets to extract more info, 
    #       branch out to different routines to use more regexes and sets to extract more info
    #   finally use inputDictionary to look up the meaning of extracted info    
    #   return results in some data structure
```

In my Main code, I import parseLineFile.py 
build myDictionary, decide mytimeCriteria and then use parseLine() to parse a file line by line.

I feel that my question is ... not stack-overflow-ic, but if you are to leave a comment of how I should ask a narrower/specific question, that's great! but please also at least mention how you would approach my problem.

Comment: I don't think anyone can usefully discuss the computational efficiency of your code when you've not actually shown the relevant bits of it.

Comment: This seems like a programmers.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: Keeping it all in its own .py file is a reasonable choice. Its contained in its own module namespace. No need to move it to a class unless you need to keep multiple instances with their own private data. Stick with what you have now.

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks that's the impression I got from what I read from other places as well. Now I can confirm that.  But some external data like the "inputDictionary" has to be decided during run time, so it can not be packaged in the .py file.  I am not sure how big of an impact is it going to be if I pass a big data structure by reference to my function everytime I run my function. I have an uneducated guess that if I can access "inputDictionary" as a self.myDictionary internally, it would be faster.

Comment: Not to worry. A big data structure passed by reference is very fast. A simple string or a `dict` with millions of entries have the same reference overhead.

Comment: @tdelaney roger, thanks. How do I accept this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to specifically tell you what you should do for this specific function, but some tips in regards to organizing big functions:

First, identify what conditionals can be moved to their own function. For example, let's say you have this code:

```
if 'foo' in inputString:
   line = regex()
   line = do_something_else()
elif 'bar' in inputString
   line = regex()
   line = do_something_a_little_different()
```

You can easily see one abstraction you could do here, and that's to move the functionality in each `if` block to its own function, so you would create `parseFoo` and `parseBar` functions which take a line, and return an expected value.

The main benefit of this is now you have extremely simple functions to unit test with!

Other things I watch out for are:

- Are you do many nesting of conditionals? Extract into a function and `return` early, to reduce nesting
- If you're repeating yourself with different inputs, extract into a function
- Mentally scan the function a day later and see if I still get it quite easily. If not, extract into smaller bits.

Anyways, more input from you would be ideal but I hope that helps to get you started!

Comment: I see my folly here... I didn't question the right way. Thank you for your advice to break up big functions, I think it is the right thing to do. My question is more like:  should I make this function not a file, but a class? should I put the regexes sets and dictionary as internal variable of the class, or should I just pass them as arguments. Or any other possibilities of organizing this big function

Comment: @YunliuStorage: Your comment here shows exactly why this isn't a good question

Comment: I am aware of that, the most "help" I get from this community are about how bad my questions are. Good questions are usually google-able.

Comment: @YunliuStorage: if you know this type of question isn't a good match for SO, then please stop asking them here.  *SO isn't intended to match every programming related educational need you might have*, and these questions diminish the value of the site. For example, it takes a long time to read a question and determine that it can't be answered without a long discussion, and you wasted many peoples' time with this.

Comment: I got my answer, I cleared my misconceptions. My questions diminish the site, and your kind diminish my estimation for this site.